# Building jupyterlab in google cloud

Tags: jupyter-lab, google-dl-platform

I have access to a google cloud compute instance where I run jupyterlab.
I updated jupyterlab to 2.1.4 but then I can't build with the extensions.

When I build in the console (The one built in jupyter lab and the one of the instance), it tells me that the build went fine but when I reload jupyterlab tells me it needs to build again.

I had some other issues such as updating a package with `pip` and when trying to use it, but the version remaining the same.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you